# Netstream() loop problem

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, for-loop

I'm preloading 4 flv movies and hide them, when I rollover the videobutton movieclip i want the flv video to fade in and start playing. I have this working code, but I feel it's very badly written.

```
var videos:Array = new Array(
'ltp_video-low1.flv',
'ltp_video-low1.flv',
'ltp_video-low1.flv',
'ltp_video-low1.flv'
);

function videoOver(buttonMC,video,stream) {
    buttonMC.onRollOver = function() {
    stream.pause(false);
    video.attachVideo(stream);
    fadeIn(video);
    };
}

function videoOut(buttonMC,video,stream) {
    buttonMC.onRollOut = function() {
    fadeOut(video);
    stream.pause();
    };
}

for (var i:Number=1; i<=4; i++) {
    this['connection'+i] = new NetConnection();
    this['connection'+i].connect(null);
    this['stream'+i] = new NetStream(this['connection'+i]);
    this['stream'+i].play(videos[i-1]);
    videoOver(this['videobutton'+i],this['video'+i],this['stream'+i]);
    videoOut(this['videobutton'+i],this['video'+i],this['stream'+i]);
}
```

Instead I want something like this:
But this doesn't work, something wrong with the attachVideo() i think.

```
for (var i:Number = 1; i<=4; i++) {
    this['connection'+i] = new NetConnection();
    this['connection'+i].connect(null);
    this['stream'+i] = new NetStream(this['connection'+i]);
    this['stream'+i].play('ltp_video-low1.flv');
    this['videobutton'+i].i = i;
    this['videobutton'+i].onRollOver = function() {
        this['stream'+this.i].pause(false);
        this.attachVideo(['stream'+this.i]);
        fadeIn(['video'+this.i]);
    };
    this['videobutton'+i].onRollOut = function() {
        this['stream'+this.i].pause();
        this.attachVideo(['stream'+this.i]);
        fadeOut(['video'+this.i]);
    };
}
```

Here is all the code:

```
// Import TweenLite
import gs.*;
import gs.easing.*;

// Creates the fade functions
function fadeIn(video) {
    TweenLite.to(video,0.5,{_alpha:100, ease:Regular.easeOut});
}
function fadeOut(video) {
    TweenLite.to(video,0.5,{_alpha:0, ease:Regular.easeOut});
}

// Parses the Flashvars into arrays
var titles:Array = (_level0.titleVars) ? _level0.titleVars.split(',') : [];
var urls:Array = (_level0.urlVars) ? _level0.urlVars.split(',') : [];

// Sets the mouse action
function SetMouseAction(indexNumber, buttonMC, arrowMC, dynamicTF, linkURL):Void {
    buttonMC.colorText = dynamicTF;
    buttonMC.onRollOver = function() {
        TweenLite.to(arrowMC,0.2,{_x:"2", _alpha:80, ease:Back.easeOut, tint:0x7cb0b7});
        this.colorText.textColor = 0x7cb0b7;
        // Fixes the Flash bug with button over each other
        if (indexNumber == 1 || indexNumber == 2 || indexNumber == 3) {
            stream1.pause(false);
            fadeIn(video1);
        }
        if (indexNumber == 4 || indexNumber == 5 || indexNumber == 6) {
            stream2.pause(false);
            fadeIn(video2);
        }
        if (indexNumber == 7 || indexNumber == 8 || indexNumber == 9) {
            stream3.pause(false);
            fadeIn(video3);
        }
        if (indexNumber == 10 || indexNumber == 11 || indexNumber == 12) {
            stream4.pause(false);
            fadeIn(video4);
        }
    };
    buttonMC.onRollOut = function() {
        TweenLite.to(arrowMC,0.2,{_x:37, _alpha:100, ease:Back.easeOut, tint:0xFFFFFF});
        this.colorText.textColor = 0xffffff;
    };
    buttonMC.onRelease = function() {
        if (linkURL) {
            getURL(linkURL);
        }
    };
}

// Loops trough all the MC
for (var i:Number = 1; i<=12; i++) {
    SetMouseAction(i,this["link"+i],this["arrow"+i],this["text"+i],urls[i-1]);
    this["text"+i].text = titles[i-1];
}





var videos:Array = new Array('ltp_video-low1.flv', 'ltp_video-low1.flv', 'ltp_video-low1.flv', 'ltp_video-low1.flv');

function videoOver(buttonMC, video, stream) {
    buttonMC.onRollOver = function() {
        stream.pause(false);
        video.attachVideo(stream);
        fadeIn(video);
    };
}

function videoOut(buttonMC, video, stream) {
    buttonMC.onRollOut = function() {
        fadeOut(video);
        stream.pause();
    };
}

for (var i:Number = 1; i<=4; i++) {
    this['connection'+i] = new NetConnection();
    this['connection'+i].connect(null);
    this['stream'+i] = new NetStream(this['connection'+i]);
    this['stream'+i].play(videos[i-1]);
    videoOver(this['videobutton'+i],this['video'+i],this['stream'+i]);
    videoOut(this['videobutton'+i],this['video'+i],this['stream'+i]);
}



/*
for (var i:Number = 1; i<=4; i++) {
    this['connection'+i] = new NetConnection();
    this['connection'+i].connect(null);
    this['stream'+i] = new NetStream(this['connection'+i]);
    this['stream'+i].play('ltp_video-low1.flv');
    this['videobutton'+i].i = i;
    this['videobutton'+i].onRollOver = function() {
        this['stream'+this.i].pause(false);
        this.attachVideo(['stream'+this.i]);
        fadeIn(['video'+this.i]);
    };
    this['videobutton'+i].onRollOut = function() {
        this['stream'+this.i].pause();
        this.attachVideo(['stream'+this.i]);
        fadeOut(['video'+this.i]);
    };
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code you have:

```
function videoOver(buttonMC,video,stream) {
  buttonMC.onRollOver = function() {
    stream.pause(false);
    video.attachVideo(stream);
    fadeIn(video);
  };
}

videoOver(this['videobutton'+i],this['video'+i],this['stream'+i]);
```

In this case attachVideo is being called on a video object.

I don't see in your code where the video objects are declared, but I'll assume it's there.

In the second piece of code you're doing this:

```
this['videobutton'+i].onRollOver = function() {
  this['stream'+this.i].pause(false);
  this.attachVideo(['stream'+this.i]);
  fadeIn(['video'+this.i]);
};
```

So the attachVideo is being called on the videobutton object, not the video object.

Also, I don't think the reference to the stream will work, as your this variable will be the videobutton, which as far as I can tell doesn't have that value defined (the "this" reference within the function() {} is not the same as the this reference outside of it).

I think the call to fadeIn might also work incorrectly, as I think the scope will be messed up.

---

Here's something that might work.  I haven't tested it at all, but hopefully you'll get the idea of what I'm trying for.

```
for (var i:Number = 1; i<=4; i++) {
  this['connection'+i] = new NetConnection();
  this['connection'+i].connect(null);
  this['stream'+i] = new NetStream(this['connection'+i]);
  this['stream'+i].play('ltp_video-low1.flv');
  this['videobutton'+i].i = i;
  setHandlers(i);
}

function onVideoButtonRollOver(i:Number):Void {
  this['stream' + i].pause(false);
  this.attachVideo(this['stream' + i]);
  this.fadeIn(this['video' + i]);
}

function onVideoButtonRollOut(i:Number):Void {
  this['stream' + i].pause();
  fadeOut(this['video' + i]);
}

function setHandlers(i:Number):Function {
  this['videobutton'+i].scope = this;
  // This essentially fixes the scope issue.  The value of i is retained
  // properly due to the property of closures.
  this['videobutton'+i].onRollOver = function() {
    this.scope.onVideoButtonRollOver.apply(this.scope, [i]);
  }
  this['videobutton'+i].onRollOut = function() {
    this.scope.onVideoButtonRollOut.apply(this.scope, [i]);
  }
}
```

Though I'm not really happy with this.  I think the code should probably be refactored so that you have a single object per group, with members like "stream", "connection", etc.  I think that would make things a lot cleaner as you wouldn't have to constantly be referring to the index.

Comment: Can you show me how I can call the video object in the second code?

Comment: I don't know where it's defined, but I'll try to come up with a way to make it work.

Comment: Thanks. Though I need a solution where everything is in the loop. Any ideas? You can get the fla file here: http://drop.io/gqdcyp3

Comment: Why does everything need to be in the loop?  That seems unnecessarily limiting.

Comment: It doesn't, but I just feel that you code is overcomplicated things. Any chance of making it shorter/easier?

Comment: The code could be condensed more, but it would just be a jumbled mess.  It's better to have it split into a couple different functions than try to jam it all into the for loop.  In the long run it'll be easier to maintain.